# How to re-associate an order from one customer to another

Tags: edit-order

I'm looking into what needs to be done to change the customer association on an order from one customer to another.

From a brief glance at the tables involved, it looks like at least the following may be needed:

- order - Change the customer_id, customer_firstname, customer_lastname, etc.
- order_address - Change the customer_address_id, firstname, lastname, etc.
- order_grid - Change the customer_id
- order_shipping_rate - Change the address_id
- quote - Probably just delete quotes with the old customer_id for simplicity.

Comment: Is this assuming that there is no associated invoice or  credit note?

Comment: @JamesAllwood nope!  Could definitely have those.  Thanks for pointing those out.  Although from a brief check, it looks like the invoice entity might not have any customer ID or info on it..?

Comment: Found this extension - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/assign-order-to-customer.html - looks like it doesn't handle shipping address / billing address, just customer ID, email, name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and put together a simple command to handle the basics:
https://github.com/kalenjordan/magerun-addons#assign-order-to-new-customer

It's only handling the customer data on the order entity right now, but based on some research, that seems to be enough to get the job done on a basic level.

It won't support re-orders as well as probably some other features too well though.